# HSQL Data Storage

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQL first time. When I connected the DatabaseMAnagerSwing using HSQL Database Server Engine, I saw that a **PUBLIC** schema is already present and it contains a few tables under that schema such as Customers, etc.

I wonder where is the data (i.e. the public schema and the tables of that schema) stored when I use the mode as **HSQL Database Server Engine**?

Can someone please explain on this?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored into a file just as it would if you were running HSQLDB in embedded mode. 
To configure where to store the files for each database managed by the server you can either supply [command line arguments](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsql_server) when starting the server:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb
```

Or resort to [Properties Files](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html#N10A68):

```
database.0=file:/opt/db/accounts
dbname.0=an_alias

database.1=file:/opt/db/mydb
dbname.1=enrollments

database.2=mem:adatabase
dbname.2=quickdb
```

The connection layer is independent from the physical layer. Which means that you can access a database file originally created by a server process in embedded mode and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, since I did not specify the location where to store the files, hence where is the file stored in my case i.e. the default location for the files storage when I dont specify any location?

Comment: According to the [Properties File Documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html#N10A68) the default value for `server.database.0` is `test`. So you will find a test folder with  the files described at [Appendix C](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apc.html). Answering your other questions, all SCHEMAS of your database will be stored in that folder, and using the same files (e.g., `test.script` + `test.log`). Take a look at [Appendix C](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apc.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Anthony covers how to specify the location of database files.

Re:  "saw that a PUBLIC schema is already present and it contains a few tables under that schema such as Customers, etc."

The PUBLIC schema is already present in a new database. But the tables you saw were created by you when you clicked on the "Options" item in the DatabaseManager menu and selected "Insert test data" from the drop down menu.

When a Server instance of HSQLDB is started without specifying the location of database files, the files are created in the directory where the Java command for starting the server was executed.

A database can contain multiple schemas. All schemas are stored in the same set of database files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where is the SCHEMA location present? Is it in the same file where the data is stored or a different file is there for this? And if I create a new schema then in which file will this new schema be stored? Please let me know the location for that also.